Staging ground question left in a half-deleted state
There was recently a run-of-the-mill AI generated / potential spam seed question in the Staging Ground, Mouse Polling Rate. It was deleted by Machavity, but it was somehow left in a strange half-deleted state. The timeline claims that there was an undeletion vote casted immediately before (or at the same time as?) the deletion vote:


While in this weird state, it was possible to:

See the question in the list of new questions



View the question below 10k reputation (note that this is not the case for properly deleted questions)



Leave comments



And perform review actions, including Approve and Publish1



This could potentially have been caused by an issue with a userscript that bypasses the delete confirmation (the bug was not able to be reproduced since). Even if this was caused by a userscript, the site accepting an undeletion vote on a non-deleted question is still a bug regardless.

1: Publishing this question was allowed for testing purposes, the published question was already deleted.

Just as an FYI, I did not vote to undelete and was just as confused by the state it was left in. Even if I had cast an undelete, the question should not have been undeleted, yet confusingly having a deleted message at the top.
